# org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletRequestContext cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.UploadContext

Tags: ajax, jsf, tomcat, cdi, multipartform-data

I have JSF/CDI application which works fine in my local windows environment.
I have a form with enctype as "multipart/form-data". In this form I'm uploading file using h:inputfile.
I also have other Calendar and text fields in this form. 
When I move this application to our IST environment in LINUX, I'm getting below exception when trying to do ajax submit of the form. I have 2 ajax submit, one involves the file upload and other with another text field. Both are throwing the below ClassCastException. I'm using JSF 2.2.5, Servlet 3, CDI bean deployed in tomcat 7.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletRequestContext cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.UploadContext
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileUploadBase.java:811) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:259) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:283) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:129) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2722) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3043) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1148) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationContextActivator.getConversationId(ConversationContextActivator.java:124) ~[weld-servlet-2.1.0.Final.jar:2013-10-11 10:25]
        at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationContextActivator.activateConversationContext(ConversationContextActivator.java:91) ~[weld-servlet-2.1.0.Final.jar:2013-10-11 10:25]
        at org.jboss.weld.servlet.HttpContextLifecycle.requestInitialized(HttpContextLifecycle.java:183) ~[weld-servlet-2.1.0.Final.jar:2013-10-11 10:25]
        at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener.requestInitialized(WeldInitialListener.java:135) ~[weld-servlet-2.1.0.Final.jar:2013-10-11 10:25]
        at org.jboss.weld.servlet.api.helpers.ForwardingServletListener.requestInitialized(ForwardingServletListener.java:42) ~[weld-servlet-2.1.0.Final.jar:2013-10-11 10:25]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.fireRequestInitEvent(StandardContext.java:5948) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:167) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(StuckThreadDetectionValve.java:193) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [catalina.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:197) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.33]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.33]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Updated:

I checked our IST server and found that tomcat-coyote.jar is different in my local and IST server. After some followups I found that the tomcat-coyote.jar was updated by our system admins for some security issues with apache file Upload. Now after doing the same patch in my local, I'm getting same error in my local also. But can someone please tell me how can I avoid this Exception. How can I convert org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletRequestContext to org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.UploadContext? Because I just use h:inputfile in my jsf page with form enctype as multipart/form-data.

Comment: Seems like a classloader problem.  What's inside your WAR and what libs are on your container?

Comment: @JohnAment, I see the tomcat-coyote.jar in our IST server has few extra classes compared to one in my local box even though the META-INF file says they both have same version - 7.0.33. We are still trying to figure out how the tomcat-coyote.jar got updated.